# Will US Embassy verify identity with and without middle name?

Tags: usa, names

I am a US citizen and have run into difficulties abroad regarding some documents containing my middle name and some without. I was given 10 days to get a 'declaration from the embassy' that 'First Last' is the same person as 'First Middle Last'.

I looked through the embassy website and I can find nothing about whether they would issue such a declaration. There is a consular appointment just before the deadline is up, so there is one chance to get it.

Does the embassy issue declarations like this? I have a passport with one name and a DL with the other. Will that be enough?

Comment: i doubt the embassy will issue such a document, but I do not know.  Is it your passport or DL that has the middle name?  What country is giving you trouble because of the mismatch (name laws vary)?

Comment: Passport does not have it, DL does. Portugal.

Comment: Also, it is on my birth certificate, but I cannot get a copy here in 10 days. It was on my old passport, but not onthe most recent one when it was renewed years ago. I never noticed or cared until now.

Comment: It's weird that the new passport didn't match the old one.  I wonder how that could happen.  I hope you can resolve this; it sounds like an utter pain in the neck.  I suppose the solution would be to get a new passport with the middle name, but I doubt you can do that in 10 days (unless you can convince the embassy to issue an emergency one for this reason).

Comment: Consular staff is very likely to ask you why, when you received your current passport, you didn't then ask DoS about the discrepancy and seek to have the passport reissued.

Comment: @David if they do ask, wouldn't "I didn't notice" be an acceptable response?

Comment: Might be, but because the passport's been used since issuance, it may not be convincing. "I didn't think it'd matter" might be better. In any event, expecting the question is going to be better than being surprised.

Comment: Regardless, they said no way to reissue passport so quickly unless it is a life or death situation. 6 more months of dealing with paperwork doesn't qualify. Does this mean I'm just out of luck and nothing to do but restart the whole process with a new passport? It sounds like no such declaration exists.

Answer (score 2):

You may be able to get by with having a statement that confirms that both names are yours and have the embassy notarize the statement.

Although they're not usually notarized, this type of statement occurs in the US when doing things like getting a mortgage. I've had to attest/confirm that 'LASTNAME FIRSTNAME', FIRSTNAME LASTNAME, FIRSTNAME MIDDLEINITIAL LASTNAME, etc. are all me. I found it listed on this notary public [site](https://www.nationalnotary.org/notary-bulletin/blog/2019/03/signing-agent-faq-signature-affidavits) as called something like Signature and Name Affidavit, Affidavit of Common Identity, and so on.

See [this page](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/legal/travel-legal-considerations/internl-judicial-asst/authentications-and-apostilles.html) which talks about the various types of notarization and attestation that can be done by embassy employees.